# Complex derivative numerically using real $h$ and imaginary $h i$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I want to find numerically (the functional expression might become too complicated) the derivative of a complex function (to use it in a Newton-algorithm). Can I simply do something like
$$ \frac {df}{dz} = \lim_{h \to 0} {f(z+h)-f(z))\over h} + {f(z+ih)-f(z))\over h} 
$$
? Or how do I have to do this?

---

[update]

By manual tests with $f(z) = \log(z)$, then $f'(z)=\frac1z$ and some examples it seems that I must do
$$ \frac {df}{dz} = \lim_{h \to 0} {{f(z+h)-f(z))\over h} + {f(z+ih)-f(z))\over ih} \over 2 }
$$
Is that formally correct?

Comment: Consider $f(z) := z$. The derivative *should be* $1$, but the formula shown gives $1+i$.

Comment: That limit seems to give $(1+i)f'(z)$…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ then
$$
 \frac{df}{dz}(z_0) = \lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ h \in \Bbb C}} {f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)\over h} \, ,
$$
in other words, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$
such that
$$
 h \in \Bbb C, |h| < \delta \Longrightarrow \left| {f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)\over h}  - \frac{df}{dz}(z_0) \right | < \varepsilon \, .
$$
In particular, this holds for $h \in \Bbb R$, and therefore
$$
 \frac{df}{dz}(z_0) = \lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ h \in \Bbb R}} {f(z_0+h)-f(z_0))\over h} \, .
$$
(But note that the existence of the complex derivative is *assumed* here.)

Your second formula is correct because
$$
 \frac{df}{dz}(z_0) = \lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ h \in \Bbb R}} {f(z_0+ih)-f(z_0))\over ih} 
$$
holds as well, as you can choose *any* sequence of values $h \in \Bbb C$
converging to zero.

See also  [Complex differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Complex_differentiability):
$$
 f'(z_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (z_0) = \frac 1i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (z_0) 
$$
if $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$.